# Why isn't Node.js coming with NPM when installed?

Tags: node.js, npm

I downloaded Node.js via https://nodejs.org/en/ and installed it successfully.  In `Terminal`, I ran the command `node -v` which then gives me `v11.2.0` indicating that Node.js is indeed installed.

However, upon running `npm -v` I get an error that says: `-bash: npm: command not found`.  I've looked at everything online, tried everything I possibly could but no luck at all.

It's very frustrating because it said that `npm` comes with node but it looks like it doesn't.

How can I fix this?

Edit: I'm on Mac

Comment: Which is you SO? As I remember, in Windows there are a check button to include de NPM on Node.js installation.

Comment: @LucasCosta I'm on MacBook.

Comment: I would suggest using "nvm" to install and manage multiple node versions. Its the most managable tool for installing and using multiple nodeJs versions

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3125

Comment: @UnholySheep Yeah I saw this and tried following the suggested answer, but had no luck.  I'm totally lost on this.